# If Else ignores all possible conditions except for the first

Tags: shopify, liquid

Our site makes use of different price breaks based on quantity, but each product category has a different price break structure. To achieve this, I link to a different pricing structure based on the title of the collection.

However, in my attempt (below), it only works in the first instance, for Jackets. If the product isn't a jacket, it skips all the next options and goes straight to the catch-all 'else' at the bottom.

The 'contains' in the first if the statement is in bold when I view it in the Shopify code editor, while the following 'contains' in the elseif statements are not. I assume that means it's invalid somewhere, but looking at their code guidelines I struggle to see where this is.

```
{% if collection.title contains 'Jackets' %}

   {% include 'jacket-pricing' %}

{% elsif collection.title contains 'Trousers' %}

   {% include 'trouser-pricing' %}

{% elsif collection.title contains 'T-Shirts' %}

   {% include 't-shirt-pricing' %}

{% elsif collection.title contains 'Polo' %}

   {% include 'polo-shirt-pricing' %}

{% elsif collection.title contains 'Gilets' %}

   {% include 'gilet-pricing' %}

{% elsif collection.title contains 'Hi-Vis' %}

   {% include 'hi-vis-pricing' %}

{% elsif collection.title contains 'Fleeces' %}

   {% include 'fleece-pricing' %}

{% elsif collection.title contains 'Headwear' %}

   {% include 'headwear-pricing' %}

{% elsif collection.title contains 'Sweatshirts' %}

   {% include 'sweatshirt-pricing' %}

{% elsif collection.title contains 'Hoodies' %}

   {% include 'hoodie-pricing' %}

{% elsif collection.title contains 'Shirts' %}

   {% include 'shirt-pricing' %}

{% elsif collection.title contains 'Vests' %}

   {% include 'vest-pricing' %}

{% elsif collection.title contains 'Tabard' %}

   {% include 'tabard-pricing' %}

{% elsif collection.title contains 'Aprons' %}

   {% include 'apron-pricing' %}

{% else %}

    catch all pricing goes here

{% endif %}
```

Comment: What is the value of `collection`?

Comment: Your code looks ok so it means conditions are not filled if else condition is applied. You must check why. 

However if I may, using collection.title is risky as it can be modified anytime by user. At least, use collection.handle to avoid mispell.

And for long list like this, case/when use can be useful: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/tags/control-flow-tags#case-when